# Add row not working for ajax sourced data

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

Below code is not adding a new row into datatable. It returns warning ("requested unknown parameter "Title" ...) and adds an empty row which suggests data is null.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/teams/ops/pidb/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mytest')/items?$filter=(Modified gt '"+datestring+"')",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: mySuccessHandler1,
    error: myErrorHandler1
});

function mySuccessHandler1(data) {
    if(data.d.results.length > 0) {
        $.each(data.d.results,function(index,item){
            tablex.row.add([{"Title":item.Title,"LastName":item.LastName,"Area":item.Area}]).draw(false);

        });
    }
```

Debuggger shows `data.d.result` showing correct value returned in `item.Title` and others.

DataTable initialized as below

```
function mySuccessHandler(data) {
            tablex = $('#patrol').DataTable({
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "Title"
            },{
                "mData": "LastName"
            }, {
                "mData": "Area"
            }],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "select": true,
            "colReorder": true,
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            }); // DataTable() closing..
```

Just to add here that i am able to insert static data using tablex.row.add() method if above DataTable is initialized as below in mySuccessHandler()

```
tablex = $('#patrol').DataTable();
```

however same method fails to read data.d.results if i initialize it using mData

Comment: Which version of DataTables are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
tablex.row.add({"Title":item.Title,"LastName":item.LastName,"Area":item.Area}).draw(false);
```